# Avoid line return when calling AINSI escape sequence

Tags: c++, linux, escaping, sequence

I made this function who change the title of a terminal window by using ainsi escape sequence but after the call of this function a line is jumped in console, how avoid this ?

```
void setConsoleTitle(std::string const& title)
{
    m_title = title;
    std::string cmd1 = "echo \"\033]0;";
    cmd1 += title;
    cmd1 += "\007\"";

    system(cmd1.c_str());
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ReallY DON'T use `system` here (it starts a new process, in which a shell is run, and then runs `echo` in that shell, and tears down that new process - which is a lot of work to output a handful of characters to the screen, that can just as well be output with `cout` or similar - `system` is acceptable to use if you, say, need to run a compiler or unpack a zip file - something that isn't easy to do in your own program). But if you insist on using `system`, then use `echo -n ...`, where `man echo` explains it as:

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

However, just using `cout` will do fine here:

```
 cout << "\033]0;" << title << "\a";
```

(`\a` is "alarm", the same as `\007` but portable in case your system doesn't use character number 7 for "ring the bell")

Why you want to print "noise" is beyond me, but the above does the same thing as your "echo" command.

Comment: Thanks,but  why I shouldn't use system ?

Comment: Okay, thanks, question is cloed, I will try to avoid call to system().